# How to test a click event in protractor for an element which do not have id

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor

We have build a website which i need to test using Protractor. The site have many elements which do not have any id. So protractor.by.id will not work here. I have the protractor.by.css option but how will I distinguish a unique element if group of element have the same css applied. Please suggest.

```
<div class="buttons contact_page"> 
<a href="http://mysite.se/om-oss/" class="btn btn-default button">Om oss</a>
<a href="http://mysite.se/offert-3/" class="btn btn-default button">Offert</a> 
<a href="http://mysite.se/tjanster/" class="btn btn-default button">Våra Tjänster</a>
</div>
```

Thanks
Utpal

Comment: The fix for is found in the below link  https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the :nth child selector with the css selector? So you could do something like:

```
var firstBtn = element(by.css('.contact_page btn:nth-child(0)')),
    secondBtn = element(by.css('.contact_page btn:nth-child(1)')),
    thirdBtn = element(by.css('.contact_page btn:nth-child(2)'))
```

Here's a good article on how nth-child works, just in case http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Let me know how it goes!

Answer (score 1):

In your case you can use :

```
element(by.partialLinkText("oss"));
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of different ways to select an element with protactor. You can take a look at protractors [unit test](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/basic/findelements_spec.js) to see all available locators.

The right locator mostly depends on your specific case to make your test be as robust as possible.

Rely on text or index could sometimes be a bit flaky and adding a specific id or css class to an element could also be an option to consider.

Comment: you solution is relay helpful but I am not getting any option to select total no of child items inside the div to write my test case. What will be option for that.

Comment: to select the total number of children you can try element.all(...).count(). Look at this test https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/spec/basic/findelements_spec.js#L395

Comment: Cauden the part which I am testing is a non angular part so it is giving error "object has no method all" and the code I have written is given like this                                                var element = driver.all(protractor.By.css('.clearfix .col206'));
        expect(element.length).toEqual(22);

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by using `by.cssContainingText()`. Check out the [docs](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText).

In your case, if you wanted to select the middle button:

```
element(by.cssContainingText('.btn', 'Om oss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will click the the second  tag.

```
element(by.css('.contact_page ')).all(by.tagName('a')).get(1).click();
```